# Inverse of this block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

I have three square real matrices $A, B$ and $C$ of the same order, say $n$. I know that $A+B$ and $C$ are invertible. Then I built a new $nN \times nN$ big block matrix as follows:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
A+B & C & C &\cdots & C \\
C & A+B & C & \cdots & C \\
C & C & A+B & \cdots & C \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
C & C & C & \cdots & A+B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is there an expression for the inverse $M^{-1}$? I tried toeplitz inverse and also block inverse but both attempts did not work.

Comment: You could try the adjugate approach. $M\textrm{adj}(M)=\textrm{adj}(M)M=\det(M)I$ You get some messiness on the determinant side since you may result in a trying to invert a matrix relation that may not be invertible. For example in the $2 \times 2$ case $\det(M)=(A+B)^2-C^2$ if you know this is invertible you get something like $M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \det(M)^{-1}(A+B) & -\det(M)^{-1}C \\ -\det(M)^{-1}C & \det(M)^{-1}(A+B) \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I guess I should use a distinct notation since that is more of a block determinant rather than the conventional one ;)

Comment: Can you compute the inverse when $n=1$?

Comment: @InMath There is a nice approach if we are given that $A+B-C$ is invertible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = A + B - C$. Suppose we know a priori that $X$ is invertible. The matrix can be expressed in the form
$$
M = I_N \otimes X + (ee^T) \otimes C
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes a Kronecker product and $e \in \Bbb R^N$ is the vector $e = (1,\dots,1)^T$. With the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), we can express $M^{-1}$ in the form
$$
M^{-1} = I_N \otimes X^{-1} - (e \otimes X^{-1}C)(I_n + N \cdot X^{-1}C)^{-1}(e^T \otimes X^{-1}).
$$
This requires only the computation of an $n\times n$ inverse

Comment: There is no loss in generality to assuming that $X$ is invertible, because this is required for the block matrix to be invertible. If $X$ is singular with null vector $u$ such that $Xu=0$, then direct calculation shows that $(u,-u,u,-u,\dots,u,-u)$ is in the null space of the block matrix for even $n$, and $(u,-u,\dots,u,-u,0)$ is in the null space for odd $n$. Actually, any block vector where you put the same number of $u$ and $-u$ blocks will be a null vector for the block matrix

Comment: @Nick Nice observation!

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks!